# Воспроизведение видео в Android приложении

Tags: android, youtube, videoview, vimeo

Не нравится мобильная версия одного сайта, поэтому решил сделать для себя приложение, которое парсит новости и отображает у меня в прилаге (текст, картинки, гифки, видео - все вперемешку).
Вопрос по видео. Все видео с данного сайта представлены в одном из трех плеерах: `youtube`, `vimeo`, `jwplayer`.  Подключать три библиотеки по каждому плееру и воспроизводить видео в зависимости от ссылки, которую я получаю при парсинге? Или можно создать `VideoView` и вне зависимости от ссылок воспроизводить любое видео в нем? Какой подход наиболее подходящий для решения моей задачи? Если есть еще лучше варианты - напишите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `ExoPlayer`.

Comment: @post_zeew хочу уточнить. Т.е. на вход этому ExoPlayer я могу подать три разные ссылки и он будет воспроизводить каждую, так?

Comment: Далеко не факт. Посмотрите в интернете информацию по этому поводу.

Comment: @post_zeew я наверное вставлю в свое приложение WebView и буду на вход ему запускать эти видюшки. Такому варианту имеет место быть? :)

Comment: Можете попробовать и так, но это некрасиво и нестабильно.